# Слияние связанных потоков данных

Tags: c++, многопоточность, инспекция-кода, архитектура, структуры-данных

(продолжение темы [про 3D-сканер](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1197938/))

**Задача:**

По сети приходит `NUM` потоков данных, являющихся частями одного потока.
Каждый элемент `chunk`-а в подпотоке индифицируется номером в общей последовательности(`seq_id`).
Элементы `chunk`-ов приходят с небольшим разбросом во времени. То есть может быть ситуация, что предыдущий `chunk` еще не закончен и пришел элемент следующего.

Элементы `chunk`-ов приходят блоками по несколько штук(количество настраивается для каждого потока). Между блоками могут быть паузы(рандом).

Ожидаемый поток данных: не более 200 `chunk` в секунду(1 `chunk` ~ 15 KiB)
Элемент чанка - массив из 1024х точек + метаданные.
Полный чанк - 3 таких массива с 3х разных железок.
Данные приходят с 3D сканеров.
Полный скан ~ 2 милиона точек(из них 2/3 - мусор)

Для дальнейшей обработки нужно слить элементы `chunk`-ов с одинаковыми `seq_id` в одно целое.

SDK от производителя камер поддерживает 3 варианта API:

- `C++ / PULL` - "ручное" управление циклом сканирования.
- `C++ / PUSH` - как я понял, это обертка над первым. Меньше кода, `Event driven`. Все что надо - это зарегистрировать `callback` и стартануть измерение.
- `C / PULL` - то же что и первое, только для "Си"

Я выбрал работу с `C++ / PUSH`:

Для получения данных запущено `NUM` `grab`-еров и один `merge`:

- `grab` получает данные по сети и производит начальную обработку элемента `chunk`-а
- `merge` объединяет элементы в целый `chunk` и обрабатывает его. Затем отправляет дальше по цепочке.

Прошу оценить выбранный подход и указать на недостатки.

**Упрощенный код**

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#include <list>

#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <chrono>
#include <condition_variable>

#include <unordered_map>
#include <queue>

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

using lock_guard = std::lock_guard<std::mutex>;
using unique_lock = std::unique_lock<std::mutex>;

std::mutex IO;

void print_thread(const char* name)
{
    lock_guard guard{IO};
    std::cout << name << " : " << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
}

void print_num(const char* name, size_t num)
{
    lock_guard guard{IO};
    std::cout << name << " : " << num << std::endl;
}

/// @brief структура чанк данных
struct chunk
{
    using value_type = int;
    using id_type = size_t;

    static constexpr auto NUM = 3u;

    /// @brief получить часть чанка по `id` потока
    value_type get(id_type id) const
    {
        return value[id];
    }

    /// @brief установить часть чанкиа по `id` потока
    void set(id_type id, value_type v)
    {
        value[id] = v;
        ready[id] = true; // пометить элемент "готово"
    }

    /// @brief проверка, что все элементы чанка заданы
    bool is_ready() const
    {
        bool all = true;

        for (auto r : ready) // для каждого из элементов чанка
        {
            all &= r;
        }
        return all;
        /* другой вариант реализации
        for (auto r : ready) // для каждого из элементов чанка
        {
            if (!r) return false;
        }
        return true;
        */
    }

    /// @brief конструктор чанка
    chunk()
    {
        // установить флаги готовностей частей
        for (auto& r : ready)
        {
            r = false;
        }
    }
private:
    /// @brief элементы чанка данных
    value_type value[NUM];
    /// @brief флаги готовности элементов чанка
    bool ready[NUM];
};


/**
 * @brief очередь чанков для слияния
 */
struct chunk_queue
{
    using seq_type = uint32_t;
    using value_type = chunk::value_type;
    using id_type = chunk::id_type;

    /// @brief проверка очереди на пустоту
    bool empty() const
    {
        lock_guard g{m};

        return queue.empty();
    }

    /// @brief получить чанки на верхушке очереди
    chunk top() const
    {
        lock_guard g{m};

        auto key = queue.front();

        return data.at(key);
    }

    /// @brief проверка, что на верхушке полный чанк
    bool data_ready()
    {
        lock_guard g{m};

        if (queue.empty())
            return false;
        
        auto key = queue.front();

        return data.at(key).is_ready();
    }

    /// @brief добавить часть чанка в очередь. Если чанк с `key` отсутствует, то создать новый
    void push(seq_type key, id_type id, value_type v)
    {
        lock_guard g{m};

        auto it = data.find(key);

        if (data.end() == it) // no data for this key, create new
        {
            auto p = data.emplace(key, chunk{});
            it = p.first;
            queue.push(key);
        }

        it->second.set(id, v);
    }

    /// @brief извлечь чанк с верхушки очереди
    void pop()
    {
        lock_guard g{m};

        auto key = queue.front();

        queue.pop();
        data.erase(key);
    }
private:
    using Queue = std::queue<seq_type>;
    using Map = std::unordered_map<seq_type, chunk>;

    Queue queue{};
    Map data{};

    mutable std::mutex m;
};

constexpr auto N = 15u;

static chunk_queue q{};

void grab(size_t id)
{
    auto i = 0u;
    while (i < N)
    {
        // wait for data
        if (0 == i % 3)
        {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(50ms);
        }
        // ... some work
        // push result to queue
        q.push(i, id, i + id);

        ++i;
    }
}

void merge()
{
    auto i = 0u;
    while (i < N)
    {
        // wait for new data
        while(! q.data_ready())
        {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(10ms);
        }
        auto p = q.top();
        q.pop();
        // process data from queue
        //....
        ++i;
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{
    std::list<std::thread> workers;

    std::thread combine;

    // потоки `grab` создаются SDK железки.
    // по одному на соединение
    for (size_t i = 0; i < chunk::NUM; i++)
    {
        workers.emplace_back(&grab, i);
    }
    

    combine = std::thread{&merge};

    combine.join();

    for (auto &w : workers)
    {
        w.join();
    }
    

    return 0;
}
```

В полном коде `chunk::value_type` - массив структур. `int` тут только для примера.

**Что мне лично не нравится:**

Постоянный поиск в `map`.

---

**UPD:** обновил код с учетом замечаний в коментариях:
[@ARHovsepyan](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/277611/)  подсказка с битовым полем.
[@avp](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/232/) намек на `std::condition_variable`

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#include <list>

#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <chrono>
#include <condition_variable>

#include <unordered_map>
#include <queue>

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

using lock_guard = std::lock_guard<std::mutex>;
using unique_lock = std::unique_lock<std::mutex>;

std::mutex IO;

void print_thread(const char* name)
{
    lock_guard guard{IO};
    std::cout << name << " : " << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
}

void print_num(const char* name, size_t num)
{
    lock_guard guard{IO};
    std::cout << name << " : " << num << std::endl;
}

constexpr uint32_t n_bits(uint32_t n)
{
    // invert 0 -> all bits == 1
    constexpr auto all_bits = ~(uint32_t{0});

    // shift and invert again -> n low bits == 1
    return ~(all_bits << n);
}

/// @brief структура чанк данных
struct chunk
{
    using value_type = int;
    using id_type = size_t;

    static constexpr auto NUM = 3u;

    /// @brief получить часть чанка по `id` потока
    value_type const& get(id_type id) const
    {
        return value[id];
    }

    /// @brief установить часть чанкиа по `id` потока
    void set(id_type id, value_type v)
    {
        value[id] = v;
        ready |= 1u << id; // пометить элемент "готово"
    }

    /// @brief проверка, что все элементы чанка заданы
    bool is_ready() const
    {
        return ALL_READY == ready;
    }

private:
    /// @brief элементы чанка данных
    value_type value[NUM];
    /// @brief флаги готовности элементов чанка
    uint32_t ready = 0;

    static constexpr uint32_t ALL_READY = n_bits(NUM);
};


/**
 * @brief очередь чанков для слияния
 */
struct chunk_queue
{
    using seq_type = uint32_t;
    using value_type = chunk::value_type;
    using id_type = chunk::id_type;

    /// @brief проверка очереди на пустоту
    bool empty() const
    {
        lock_guard g{access};

        return queue.empty();
    }

    /// @brief получить чанки на верхушке очереди
    chunk top() const
    {
        lock_guard g{access};

        auto key = queue.front();

        return data.at(key);
    }

    /// @brief проверка, что на верхушке полный чанк
    bool data_ready()
    {
        lock_guard g{access};

        if (queue.empty())
            return false;
        
        auto key = queue.front();

        return data.at(key).is_ready();
    }

    /// @brief добавить часть чанка в очередь. Если чанк с `key` отсутствует, то создать новый
    void push(seq_type key, id_type id, value_type v)
    {
        lock_guard g{access};

        auto it = data.find(key);

        if (data.end() == it) // no data for this key, create new
        {
            auto p = data.emplace(key, chunk{});
            it = p.first;
            queue.push(key);
        }

        auto& current = it->second;
        current.set(id, v);

        if (current.is_ready())
        {
            notify_ready();
        }
    }

    /// @brief извлечь чанк с верхушки очереди
    void pop()
    {
        lock_guard g{access};

        auto key = queue.front();

        queue.pop();
        data.erase(key);
    }

    /// @brief дождаться готовности
    void wait4ready()
    {
        unique_lock lock{event};
        ready_event.wait(lock); // TODO: timeout
    }

    /// @brief уведомить о готовности
    void notify_ready()
    {
        ready_event.notify_all();
    }
private:
    using Queue = std::queue<seq_type>;
    using Map = std::unordered_map<seq_type, chunk>;

    Queue queue{};
    Map data{};

    mutable std::mutex access, event;
    std::condition_variable ready_event;
};

constexpr auto N = 15u;

static chunk_queue q{};

void grab(size_t id)
{
    auto i = 0u;
    while (i < N)
    {
        // wait for data
        if (0 == i % 3)
        {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(50ms);
        }
        // ... some work
        // push result to queue
        q.push(i, id, i + id);

        ++i;
    }
}

void merge()
{
    auto i = 0u;
    while (i < N)
    {
        // wait for new data
        while(! q.data_ready())
        {
            q.wait4ready();
        }
        auto p = q.top();
        q.pop();
        // process data from queue
        //....
        ++i;
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{
    std::list<std::thread> workers;

    std::thread combine;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < chunk::NUM; i++)
    {
        workers.emplace_back(&grab, i);
    }
    

    combine = std::thread{&merge};

    combine.join();

    for (auto &w : workers)
    {
        w.join();
    }
    

    return 0;
}
```

---

**P.S.:** Принимается любая критика и/или предложения.

Comment: Обратите внимание например что делает is_ready. Она практически не возвращает просто  `ready[NUM - 2] & ready[NUM - 1]`?  Или я ошибаюсь?...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, обновил коментарии к коду

Comment: Да, верно,  но все таки я реализовал бы по другому(не функцию, а весь код), но это долгий разговор...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, а если в двух словах?

Comment: В двух словах у вас много лишнего, можно создать просто битовое поле(не целый массив) для обозначения  или  вообще использовал бы просто std::array<std::pair<int, bool>  вместо chunk. Я просто написал свое мнение, но в данный момент нет времени обсуждать, за что извиняюсь

Comment: Мне не нравится активное ожидание очередного seq_id в `merge()`.  Я бы сделал обнаружение завершения заполнения всеми чанками очередного сообщения в `grab()` (можно смотреть все ready, а можно сделать  счетчик в `chunk` и как только он стал N, то весь chunk готов) и посылал из него notify в merge. (откровенно, не знаю, как в С++ multy-threading реализовааны `pthread_cond_t`,  `pthread_cond_signal()` и релевантные вызовы)

Comment: Использование map очевидно оправдано только если скорость генерации чанков сильно варьируется. Если же она примерно одинакова, то возможно лучшим решением будет последовательный поиск нужного seq_id (принимая во внимание, что они монотонно растут, следовательно спиcок (очередь) будет упорядочена по seq_id)

Comment: Код вообще слабо связан с задачей. Сетевого взаимодействия не видно, однако вместо него зачем-то создается NUM + 1 тредов, когда одного должно хватить за глаза.

Comment: @user7860670, используется SDK от производителя. Для обмена данными с железками создается поток, который подписывается на события от SDK. Вернее SDK создает отдельный поток для каждого соединения.

Comment: @MaximTimakov, реально, данные в каждом чанке это одно число? (вообще, опишите данные поподробней)

Comment: @avp, элемент чанка - массив из 1024х точек + метаданные. Полный чанк - 3 таких массива с 3х разных железок. Данные приходят с 3D сканеров. полный скан ~ 2 милиона точек. из них 2/3 - мусор.

Comment: Т.е. поток данных ~3Mbit/sec (~300Kbyte). Очевидно, что это немного. Практически, ваша реализация должна нормально работать даже с map и активным ожиданием (тут величину задержки, конечно, надо подбирать на реальных данных)

Comment: imho переменная `lock` в `wait4ready()` не может быть локальной (какая-то ссылка на нее должна быть в condition variable `ready_event`). Т.е. `lock` надо вынести в экземпляр класса `chunk_queue`

Comment: @avp, как я понимаю, там связь через `mutex`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable . `lock` только запирает `mutex` при заходе в метод.

Comment: @MaximTimakov, пардон (дурацкий все же язык, этот С++), не заметил сразу, что `lock{event}` ссылается на `private mutex event`. Т.е. похоже все правильно